IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin File: Slow Syntax Highlighting and Analysis for Specific File - How to fix?
I'm encountering an issue with a specific Kotlin file in IntelliJ IDEA. Specifically, when editing the file named crate.kt, the syntax highlighting and code analysis take an unreasonably long time to complete. Even simple tasks like highlighting the WeightedChance tier (e.g., COMMON) and item names (e.g., BRONZE_BOLTS), as well as minimum and maximum amounts, take significantly longer than usual. Additionally, if the file contains a long list, IntelliJ IDEA never finishes analyzing the file.
This issue persists across multiple computers and IntelliJ IDEA installations. Other Kotlin files work perfectly fine, and this problem is isolated to the crate.kt file. I've tried updating IntelliJ IDEA, adjusting syntax highlighting settings, clearing caches, and checking for plugin compatibility, but the problem persists.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this slow syntax highlighting and analysis issue specific to the crate.kt file in IntelliJ IDEA? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a snippet:
package com.sakra.rs2.content.survival.loot.impl

import com.sakra.core.util.chance.Chance
import com.sakra.core.util.chance.WeightedChance
import com.sakra.rs2.content.survival.Constants
import com.sakra.rs2.content.survival.loot.Loot
import com.sakra.rs2.content.survival.loot.LootItem

class Crate : Loot {
override fun name() = "Crate"
override fun objectId() = 63
override fun emptyObjectId() = 354
override fun respawnInTicks() = 10
override fun rolls() = 2
override fun items() = Chance(
    listOf(
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_PLATEBODY)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_PLATELEGS)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_SWORD)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_SCIMITAR)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_DAGGER)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_BATTLEAXE)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_MACE)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_LONGSWORD)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_LONGSWORD)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_CROSSBOW)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_DART,1,100)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_KNIFE,1,100)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_THROWNAXE,1,100)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_ARROW,1,100)),
        WeightedChance(WeightedChance.COMMON, LootItem(Constants.Items.BRONZE_BOLTS,1,100)),

)
)
}

TLDR: Highlighting a certain Kotlin file takes way too long or even never finishes, leaving me with a plain white Kotlin code file without any usable highlights.

Please create a ticket to YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue
And provide reports captured for performance issues:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems
